# Can I be notified when Google indexes a web page (either mine or a competitor's)?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, notification

Is there a way to be notified by Google (or someone else) when Google indexes a new page on a website?

I have a few websites that I want to keep track of and be notified when they add new products to their websites.

I've tried using https://google.com/alerts and `site:example.com` but this isn't really working. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you should just add an `inurl` parameter (assuming you know it ;) ), like this:

[image]

After this url appears in the index, it triggers an alert.